# For which values of k are O(n+k) and O(n+k*logk) linear?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

How would i go about finding these values? The time complexities are both related to sorting algorithms. In both cases, k represents the number of different elements in the list to be sorted. Intuitively we should have linear O(n) time if k is small relative to n in both cases but is there a more strict set of values?

In the case of O(n+k), I tried by simply assumning that k has to be O(n) but i have a hard time defining exatly what that would mean. For example if n=100 and k=200, I assume that would be linear time since k is O(n) but if k=10000 we would say its O(n^2). Where would the limit for linear time be?

I would appreciate any help, Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't really matter what value k is, the question who have to ask is "Is it constant?   or does it depend on the input size (n) ".   If it is constant, both O(n + k) and O(n + klogk) is O(n) algorithms.  But if k is some function f(n)  (i.e. it increases as the size of the input to the algorithm increases). Then the running time of the algorithms are O(n + f(n) ) and O(n + f(n) log f(n) ) .  Depending on whether or not f(n) grows asymptotically faster than O(n) will then give the final running time of the algorithms.

Comment: To stress this.  If for an algorithm k always = 10000000000, no matter the input size, then O(n + k) is still linear. Very slow, yes, but linear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am unsure of whether k is considered a constant or not. If we take counting sort as an example, k is the number of different elements. This depends on the list of elements but not the amount (n). Would k be considered a constant in that case? I do however agree with what you wrote since the k operations will be constant as n increases. It just feels like a redundant question to be given if it turns out that the value of k is irrelevant but maybe that is what was meant to be understood.

Comment: Depending on your implementation of your counting sort.  If the algorithm determine its own k (i e, counts the number of different elements and then applies counting sort i would say that it is a function of n (as there is no guarantee there isn't O(n) different elements).  But, normally you give the k to counting sort as a sort of guarantee that there isn't more than k elements. In that case it is a constant.